# Quickly move browser viewed PDF to local PDF reader

Tags: browser, pdf, search, adobe-reader, embedded

I have a problem where I wish to open PDF's in Adobe Reader so that I can search through them.
When I open them in my web browser (I am using Chrome) under some sites I can't search through them, however, I do like to be able to skim through them in my browser so I wish to keep this functionality.

Is there a way to simply move the PDF from the web browser to Adobe Reader without having to save, choose another path for the document and open it separately?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Forgot to mention that. I am using Chrome. (Edited the Question)